# How to reset bash config?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu

Previously, when I mistakenly entered a wrong command in the terminal, I would get an output like this:

```
Command 'whoaim' not found, did you mean:

    command 'whoami' from deb coreutils (8.30-3ubuntu2)
    
Try: sudo apt install <deb name>
```

but now when I enter a wrong command like `whoaim` instead of `whoami` I get this output:

```
bash: whoaim: command not found
```

how should I reset bash config?

Comment: Recommend you to use this command line tool [thefuck](https://github.com/nvbn/thefuck).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reset the bash profile of user using following commands:-

Overwrite the existing `.bashrc` from user's home directory.

```
cp /etc/skel/.bashrc ~/

source ~/.bashrc
```

Take backup of existing **.bashrc** from user's home directory

However, check [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/67466/how-to-implement-package-install-suggestion-on-debian) how you can use the utility `command-not-found` in ubuntu

Comment: Thanks, but overwriting the .bashrc did not change the output.

Comment: You can check the answer by codemonkey or the link that I mentioned in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You would need to call a function that gives bash this capability. It's typically called `command_not_found_handle`. First, append it to your `.bashrc` file. Here is the code:

```
command_not_found_handle () 
{ 
    if [ -x /usr/lib/command-not-found ]; then
        /usr/lib/command-not-found -- "$1";
        return $?;
    else
        if [ -x /usr/share/command-not-found/command-not-found ]; then
            /usr/share/command-not-found/command-not-found -- "$1";
            return $?;
        else
            printf "%s: command not found\n" "$1" 1>&2;
            return 127;
        fi;
    fi
}
```

And then run this command to reload the profile file:

```
. ~/.bashrc
```